# Importing a Github project into an Android tablet

Tags: android, git, github, import, tablet

I am trying to do Android development on an Android tablet. The program I use is called Anjedi. One of the options to create a new project is to import one from Github. It is asking for a url, so I typed https://github.com/kokas/geoquiz.git. It responded with an "imported succesfully", but then when I review the project's files, they are the git files, not the ones that belong to an android application project. Have I used the wrong url?

Comment: You probably checked out a mirror or bare repository instead of the files within the github repo. I guess the best place to look for help is on the forums for Anjedi perhaps they provide a workflow to checkout a github repo correctly.